# Python, transforming html table into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to transform my html tables into usable dataframe by using parser.make2d function, but I cannot install the module of parser.make2d. 
In my python 2.7, it cannot find the "html_table_parser" module, so that "from html_table_parser import parser_functions as parse" does not work.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import requests
from html_table_parser import parser_functions as parse

report = requests.get(url_parsing, proxies = proxies)
report2 = BeautifulSoup(report.text,'html.parser')
body=report2.find("body")
table=body.find_all("table")
p = parser.make2d(table[3])
```

Comment: How did you download the library? Using pip?

Comment: Im currently using pycharm 2017.2

Comment: Didn't use pycharm before, but will this help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: nah, html_table_parser is not in there, cant' find the module

Answer (score 0):

It seems the html_table_parser module is not installed.

Have you tried running

```
python -m pip install html_table_parser
```

on the command line?